# Fetching Multiple CRUD-able Objects From Single AngularJS Resource

Tags: angularjs, crud, angularjs-resource

How can I request a group of database entries from a AngularJS's `$resource`, which will allow my to modify and `$save()` the individual objects?

I have the following code fetching my data:

```
var VisitorLog = $resource('/visitorLog/api/v1/entry/:id',
    { id: '@id' }
);

VisitorLog.get(
    {
        'group__exact': $routeParams.groupId,
        'order_by': 'name'
    },
    function(response) {
        $scope.people = response.objects;
    },
    function(response) {
        console.log("failed!")
        console.log(response);
    }
);
```

What I would like to do is something similar to:

```
$scope.people[0].date = today;
$scope.people[0].$save();
```

This would allow me to update the UI (I have an `ng-class` watching the `date` variable) and save to the database in one call.  Am I able to do this?